# Using a php Form Processing Page sometimes includes the HTML elements in the output

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am submitting a form using Ajax to a Form processing page.

It works properly but randomly the output being sent to the user is including parts of the HTML elements that are used to construct the outgoing messages or random spaces appear in between the letters.

Below is the Form Code for processing.

```
    // Data Time Stamp for submission
$submit_date = date("l jS F Y h:i:s A");

// Meeting Request Message Build code
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<br>';
$message .= '<table class="emailform" rules="all" style="margin:10px auto; border:1px solid #f8981d; table-layout: fixed;">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #f8981d; color:#FFFFFF' ><td colspan='2' class='centered-cell'><strong><center>Meeting Request Form</center></strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td>" . $emp_Name . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $emp_Email . "</td></tr>";
if($req_Name != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Requestor's Name:</strong></td><td>" . $req_Name . "</td></tr>";
}
if($req_Email != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Requestor's Email:</strong></td><td>" . $req_Email . "</td></tr>";
}
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Function:</strong> </td><td>" . $meeting_Function . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Setup Date & Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $borrow_Date . " " . $time_Setup ."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Start Date & Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $borrow_Date . " " . $time_Actual ."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Return Date & Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $return_Date . " " . $end_Time ."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Location:</strong> </td><td>" . $Loc ."</td></tr>";

if($contact_Number != "") {
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Contact Number:</strong></td><td>" . $contact_Number . "</td></tr>";   
}

if($hw_LcdProjectorQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Projector</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_LcdProjectorQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_LaptopQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Laptop</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_LaptopQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_WiredMouseQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Wired Mouse</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_WiredMouseQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_WiredKeyboardQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Wired Keyboard</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_WiredKeyboardQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_iPadQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>iPad</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_iPadQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_RemoteMouseQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Remote Mouse</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_RemoteMouseQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_PowerStripQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Power Strip</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_PowerStripQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_HandMicQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Hand Microphone</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_HandMicQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_LapelMicQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Lapel Microphone</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_LapelMicQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_MediaCart != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Media Cart</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_MediaCart . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_PolyComPhone != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Polycom Conference Phone</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_PolyComPhone . "</td></tr>";
}

if($Applications != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Applications Requested:</strong></td><td>" . $Applications . "</td></tr>";
}

if($Comment != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Comments/Special Instructions:</strong></td><td>" . $Comment . "</td></tr>";
}

$message .= "<tr style='background: #f8981d;  color:#FFFFFF'><td><strong>Status:</strong> </td><td>Request Submitted</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

// send mails
$sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message, $headers, $ical);

if(!$sentMail)
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Your Request has been sent. Thank you'));     
    die($output);
}
}
```

Below is an example of this random issue. (this is the output in a email table. notice the Quantity has a broken space in it.

```
Borrow Request Form
Name:   My Name
Email:  myemail@email.com

Requestor's Name:   User Name
Requestor's Email:  user@email.com

Function:   Test Meeting Request
Setup Date & Time:  08/22/2014 
Start Date & Time:  08/22/2014 08:00am
Return Date & Time:  08/22/2014 09:00am
Location:   San Francisco
Laptop  Quanti ty: 1
Applications Requested: Citrix
Comments/Special Instructions:  Test Borrow Request without Submit to Service Desk Plus.
tatus:  Request Submitted
```

I do see other random character's Show up spaces, Apostrophes, Element tags like td randomly show in the output as well. I have a feeling I can buffer it to prevent these output artifacts but I learn best by example.

Thanks,

Comment: it's possible the email client is interpreting it's own line breaking mechanism as it thinks the source code is all one big line.   Try adding in some line feeds to the end of your statements, such as replacing the closing td and row like: "</td></tr>\r\n";

Comment: I will try this and see if it helps. Well now that I think about it. If this was the case then I would see the problem every time. However It's completely random. Sometimes the Emails are outputted correctly and other times it's got the artifacts such as HTML tags or random Spaces being introduced. I say 8 out of 10 emails being sent.

Comment: Have you tried echo'ing $message and viewing the DOM source to see if anything funky got in there?

Comment: Same Result. When Echoing the $message php variable. In the failed attempt the TD tag for one of the if statements was outputted.

Answer (score 0):

After laptop there isn´t a : in the code, so there cant be one. And the space in the middle of the Quantity is very mysterious.

I don´t know if this is correct but if after Laptop the : schould be, the code has to be like that:

```
[...]<tr><td><strong>Laptop:</strong></td><td>Quantity[...]
```

and the other thing that i would say , if the : is correct try this:

```
[...]<tr><td><strong>Projector Quantity:</strong></td><td>[...]
```

maybe the space disappear ;)

Comment: Yes I correct this in my code already and edited it out of the original question. However this does not explain why artifacts are breaking through. Ultimately this is being viewed as a email in Outlook.